# ImportError:'save_weights' requires h5py

Tags: keras

When I save weights during training my CNN model using keras, it says `ImportError:'save_weights' requires h5py`, but I have already installed h5py.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain how to fix this issue.

Comment: which answer worked for you? Please select it as an answer, it will be helpful to future visitors like myself.

Answer (score 7):

Just install necessary packages

`sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

`pip install h5py`

Comment: And for MacOS X ?

Comment: Once I successfully performed `pip install h5py`, I had to exit my python session for things to take effect and that's likely caused by the `try/except ImportError` in keras [sourcecode](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a6afe7c8149c61372b2aae6ae331d1584eb8a19e/keras/models.py#L20) that had assigned `None` to `h5py` when it was not able to locate it the first time it was being executed.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows and python IDE, open `cmd` and input following commands:

```
pip install h5py

pip install cython
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error as you.
I installed all the requirements listed here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3426

Finally just needed to reboot and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by others:

```
pip install h5py
```

Note that this may not immediately resolve the issue in your active session and you may need to reload `keras.models` either through the following commands or by just creating a new session/re-opening your jupyter notebook.

In Python3:

```
from importlib import reload
reload(keras.models)
```

In Python2:

use `importlib.import_module` instead. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) for a reference.

These additional steps may be necessary because of the `try/except ImportError` in keras [sourcecode](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a6afe7c8149c61372b2aae6ae331d1584eb8a19e/keras/models.py#L20) that assigns `h5py = None` when it's unable to locate it the first time it's executed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, re-installing did the trick:

```
pip uninstall -y cython h5py
pip install cython h5py
```

(Windows 10, Conda, Keras 2.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may miss this
`from keras.applications import imagenet_utils`

Comment: what is the rationale behind this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem even though I have imported the h5py.
It is the load error with the keras. It has to be reloaded.

```
import keras
from importlib import reload
reload(keras.models)
```

It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

h5py==2.10.0 works well with TF >= 2.1 so try 'pip install h5py==2.10.0'

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem where the error suggested installing h5py, but it was already installed.

If you're using miniconda like I was, this is what worked for me:

1. Uninstall h5py from everywhere, on your Anaconda Prompt:

```bash
pip uninstall h5py

pip3 uninstall h5py

conda uninstall h5py
```

Restart the anaconda prompt

2. Install it using conda only:

```bash
conda install h5py
```

Restart the anaconda prompt

I assume there was some clash when it was installed using both pip and conda. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried directly installing h5py? http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html

Try running:

`pip install h5py`
or
`sudo apt-get install libhdf5`

Comment: I was facing similar issue and installing h5py solved my issue. However, If this doesn't help then you can also try "sudo apt-get install libhdf5". Restart your terminal after that.